# GraphQL search OR operator

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, strapi

I'd like to do some search on GraphQL base on different columns, for example, if a string is equal to the first name or the last name.

I would like to be able to do something like that:

```
{
  clients(where: {or: [{firstName_contains: "example"}, {lastName_contains: "example"}]}){
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    phone
  }
}
```

Or if there is a way to do an aggregation on multiple where.

The api is built on Strapi JS, but the queries should be standard.

**System:**

1. Node.js version: 10.13.0
2. NPM version: 6.12.0
3. Strapi version: 3.0.0-beta.17.1
4. Database: SQLite
5. Operating system: Ubuntu

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello! Sadly, there is currently no way to do that right now.

Comment: Since I was at the beginning I switched my project to Adonis JS to be able to do it. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_or`. Refer the documentation [here](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/queries/query-filters.html#using-multiple-filters-in-the-same-query-and-or)
.Though the reference documentation is for Hausra but the syntax works for Strapi( tested for v 3.4.1) as well.

```
{
  clients(where: {_or: [{firstName_contains: "example"}, {lastName_contains: "example"}]}){
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    phone
  }
}
```

Comment: This is Hasura specific so people not using Hasura would need a different way most likely implementing themselves in most cases.

Comment: FYI, the question is for Strapi, and the above syntax works for strapi as well.!!